# Twilio conference Room ...how to get conference room name?

Tags: c#, twilio, conference

I was looking for some good resource for setting up a conference call feature using Twilio and came across this link.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/moderated-conference

This link is a great resource. But I am unable to understand how to get the conference room name?

In the above link the conference room is set as "My Room". Should I use a random name ? or should I create this room somewhere (like twilio account page) before using it ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Conference rooms are transient.

When you use the `<Conference>` noun, if a conference with the name you provided in the TwiML does not yet exist, Twilio will automatically create it for you.  We will also automatically destroy the conference room once all participants have left.

You can use whatever string you want for the conference name.

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please help me ? in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476090/twilio-conference-call-android-app

Comment: can you elaborate more about this? thanks :)