# Twilio - conference call android app

Tags: android, twilio

I want to make such an android app in which user can make conference call. user can add twilio user and non twilio ( can call to any phone number ) as well in a same call.
I have seen [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) , [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call) and also [this link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/setup) .
    Which path should i follow or how can i use twilio in my app?
    Should i use Rest apis or twilio java sdk or the combination of both ?
    Please guide me waiting for your valuable response ?
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: @philnash please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. In [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html) I wrote about the pitfalls of using twilio directly from your device while trying to send SMS messages.

As it happens, the same problem exists while trying make calls. You shouldn't use the REST api directly from the device, but if you're trying to make VOIP calls from it, [this example](https://github.com/mplacona/android-twilio-client) I created should be helpful to you.

In that, I use the [Twilio Android SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) to create a new VOIP call from the device. You will still need to authenticate though, but on the blog post I mentioned above I describe how to build a backend to do that.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply i will look into given links and get back to you if need more help. hope you don't mind to help me again :)

Comment: I tried the given git hub code and listening voice message about update account .how to get rid off with this message?

Comment: You will need to upgrade your account and the message will go away.

Comment: your examples are awesome. it is working for one to one call. how can i use it to make conference call from my android app? Please help me

Comment: I assume you have a TwiML app that points to a URL that connects calls using `<Dial>` with a `<Number>` or `<Client>` nested. You'll need to update that to use `<Conference>` instead. Check out the documentation for that here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference

Comment: I use server.py file found https://github.com/twilio/mobile-quickstart
i am using below code for conference and its working fine now.
resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    with resp.dial() as dial:
     # Let's use the right attribute now.
        dial.conference("Khizar test conference")

Now i want to add a PSTN call in existing conference how can i do this Please help?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a notification on this thread. You can either set up a number that PSTN numbers can call with the webhook URL set to point at the same TwiML. Or you can generate a call with the REST API and when it connects, also point the call to your conference TwiML there.

Comment: Thanks for your help we made progress now i have another question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168229/twilio-calling-app-bill-deduction
Please answer it thanks