# Detecting when a Twilio REST API call is terminated

Tags: rest, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

Using the Twilio `REST API` and `Conference` you can create a call between the caller and the rep that the rep can leave and re-enter by pressing * or 0.

When the rep presses * within a `Conference` the script on the reps end removes them from the `Conference` and takes them to a backend where they can find out what the customer needs, leaving the caller in an empty `Conference` until the rep re-joins by pressing 0.

If the rep hangs up *within* the `Conference`, the callback "`$_POST['CallStatus'] = completed`" is made. This lets the script know to end all open `Conference`s, thus redirecting any waiting callers to the main menu.

However if the rep hangs up while outside of the `Conference` *(using the backend, while a caller remains waiting)* the same callback is not made.

**What variables would indicate that the `REST API` call to the rep has hung up?** *I thought it was `$_POST['CallStatus']` or `$_POST['DialCallStatus']` but I've listened for both but have not been able to produce an on-disconnect callback for the rep's end.*

The following variables are sent to `Calls.xml` via the `REST API`:

`From => $from`

`To => $to`

`Url => $script_url`

`StatusCallback => $callback_url`

`StatusCallbackEvent => array( "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed" )`

*`$callback_url` works and detects `$_POST['CallStatus'] = in-progress` but not `completed`. (unless the rep hangs up within the conference, then it works as intended)*

CALL FUNCTION

```
class Call
{
    var $url    = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXX/Calls.xml';
    var $from   = '+1XXXXXX';

    function dial( $number, $script, $callback = false )
    {
        $switch = 'http://XXXXXX.com/' . $script . '.php';

        $post = array( 'From' => $this->from, 'To' => $number, 'Url' => $switch );

        if ( $callback )
        {
            $post['StatusCallback'] = $callback;
            $post['StatusCallbackEvent'] = array( "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed" );
        }   

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'XXXXXX:XXXXXX' );

        if ( $post )
        {
            $data = array();

            foreach ( $post as $property => $value )
            {
                array_push( $data, $property . '=' . $value );
            }

            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, implode( '&', $data ) );        
        }

        $page = curl_exec( $curl );

        curl_close( $curl );

        return $page;
    }
}
```

THE CALL

```
$call = new Call;
$call->dial( $number, $script, $callback );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You get that callback with the `completed` status when the rep hangs up during the call due to the nature of the [`action` attribute on the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) verb. However, once you are outside of a `<Dial>` then you no longer have that.

There is a way to do this though! You need to set up to receive call progress events. You can register to receive webhooks for various events that a call goes through, from queued through to completed. You can register for these using the [`StatusCallback` and `StatusCallbackEvent` parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter) when generating a call from the REST API. You can then get a webhook when the call is over, even when you outside of a `<Dial>`.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing those, edited. Right now the callback page simply creates a random text file with the `$_POST` and `$_GET`. I can access the page directly and it works. This page is also an absolute URL under "StatusCallBack". Using two phones I simulated both persons and after hanging up as the rep still no request is being sent to the callback page. (no new text files, but when i access the page directly, yes).  Do you happen to see anything in my script or methodology here that would explain that? Thanks again

Comment: Can you share the code you have used to set up your callbacks?

Comment: Yes, edited. callback is an absolute url on the same server.

Comment: And you're saying you get no events from the call at all? Is there anything in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger?quickDate=24) suggesting it can't reach your server?

Comment: Sure enough there was ! `One or more of the StatusCallbackEvents provided were invalid.` Fixed and working as intended now that `StatusCallback` and `StatusCallbackEvent` are properly set. Thanks again phil! Great service btw (if you work there)

Comment: @philnash can you please help me in this thread ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476090/twilio-conference-call-android-app/38492038#38492038